# How to delete unneeded files from a npm frontend package in production

Tags: typescript, npm, angular, browserify, node-modules

I have a frontend web app created using Angular 2 and TypeScript, and I just can't find a way to properly organize the build process.

Let's say I have this structure which I think is reasonable:

```
/
 - dist/   <-- transpiled .js files
 - src/    <-- .ts files
 - assets/
 - bower_components/
 - node_modules/
 - package.json
 - index.html
```

### Question 1

Of course I'd like not to have the `src` folder on the production server. But when should I delete it, if I should? With a npm script? With a Grunt task? With a `rm` when creating a Docker image?

The same thing applies for `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js`.

### Question 2

A similar issue comes from the `node_modules` folder: I use Browserify to bundle most of the dependencies of my app into a single file, so for example Angular becomes part of `dist/bundle.js`.

Should I delete `node_modules` on the production server, given that it isn't useful anymore? How?

For some reason I might use some modules that won't get included into the final bundle (e.g. because they're referenced from `<script>` tags): how do I know what to delete and what to keep?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your TS/JS is entirely client-side (in-browser).

In that case, if your project contains no server-side code, I've seen a lot of projects use something like a `www` folder that represents the URL scheme of the website predeployment. Everything outside of `www` is only for development (src, node_modules, etc.). Keeps deploying simple :)